# Enable LLVM + Clang in Xcode new project causes linking errors

Tags: xcode, cocoa, linker, llvm-clang

I've done a complete clean uninstall of XCode and deleted the prefs and deleted complete /Developer folder and reinstalled XCode again.

I create a new Cocoa application, go over to Target, doing a "Get info" in the target and enable "C / C++ compiler version" to "LLVM compiler 1.0.2" and press Build.

I get:

```
ld: warning: directory '/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/x86_64' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/x86_64' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/usr/lib/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/../../../i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/../../..' following -L not found
ld: library not found for -lgcc
Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Anyone able to help me here? LLVM + GCC frontend does work though but I really would like to use Clang (LLVM compiler 1.0.2). New XCode install, new Cocoa project still have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by creating two symbolic links

`/usr/lib/gcc` -> `/Developer/usr/lib/gcc`

and

`/usr/lib/i686-apple-darwin10` -> `/Developer/usr/lib/i686-apple-darwin10/`

Thanks for answering guys.