# Xcode 4.2 cannot build anything

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, osx-lion, xcode4.2

I've recently installed Xcode 4.2 on my macbookpro 10.7.2 . I have my drived partitioned by BootCamp. When I installed XCode 4.2, I ran XCode and I try to see if it can simply build stuff so I picked a Command Line Tool. When the wizard is done generating the files, I simply ran it and it already gave me an error. I tried other templates and it generated the same error. Whats the solution for this problem?

Anyway, this is the error:

```
Clang LLVM 1.0 Error
Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 11

ProcessPCH /Users/revin122/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SecondApp-dderlmctlgoalofwkqvuhanbimji/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/SecondApp-Prefix-grjbjgpsgeilsbghzjmhjjxmgsqx/SecondApp-Prefix.pch.pth SecondApp/SecondApp-Prefix.pch normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/revin122/Downloads/Ex_Files_ObjC_EssT/exercise_files/ch03/SecondApp
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Developer/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -fdiagnostics-show-category=id -fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DDEBUG -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -fasm-blocks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -Wno-sign-conversion "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -iquote /Users/revin122/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SecondApp-dderlmctlgoalofwkqvuhanbimji/Build/Intermediates/SecondApp.build/Debug/SecondApp.build/SecondApp-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/revin122/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SecondApp-dderlmctlgoalofwkqvuhanbimji/Build/Intermediates/SecondApp.build/Debug/SecondApp.build/SecondApp-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/revin122/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SecondApp-dderlmctlgoalofwkqvuhanbimji/Build/Intermediates/SecondApp.build/Debug/SecondApp.build/SecondApp-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/revin122/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SecondApp-dderlmctlgoalofwkqvuhanbimji/Build/Intermediates/SecondApp.build/Debug/SecondApp.build/SecondApp-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/revin122/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SecondApp-dderlmctlgoalofwkqvuhanbimji/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Users/revin122/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SecondApp-dderlmctlgoalofwkqvuhanbimji/Build/Intermediates/SecondApp.build/Debug/SecondApp.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/revin122/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SecondApp-dderlmctlgoalofwkqvuhanbimji/Build/Intermediates/SecondApp.build/Debug/SecondApp.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/revin122/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SecondApp-dderlmctlgoalofwkqvuhanbimji/Build/Products/Debug -c /Users/revin122/Downloads/Ex_Files_ObjC_EssT/exercise_files/ch03/SecondApp/SecondApp/SecondApp-Prefix.pch -o /Users/revin122/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SecondApp-dderlmctlgoalofwkqvuhanbimji/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/SecondApp-Prefix-grjbjgpsgeilsbghzjmhjjxmgsqx/SecondApp-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/revin122/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SecondApp-dderlmctlgoalofwkqvuhanbimji/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/SecondApp-Prefix-grjbjgpsgeilsbghzjmhjjxmgsqx/SecondApp-Prefix.pch.d

Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 11
```

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999633/enable-llvm-clang-in-xcode-new-project-causes-linking-errors).

Comment: @DuncanBabbage Is it? The error message is completely different.

Comment: Hmm, OK, actually, I might be wrong about that. :)

Comment: Tou could try using the gcc 4.2 compiler - [How to use gcc 4.2 with Xcode 4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786302/how-to-use-gcc-4-2-with-xcode-4-2).

Answer (score 0):

To try and narrow down the problem here, one thing to try would be to change the compiler from "Apple LLVM Complier 3.0" to "LLVM GCC 4.2" and see if you get different results. That might start to narrow down what is going on.

The other thing worth trying is just to re-install Xcode 4.2. A few people—myself included—found the initial install was bad but reinstalling over the top fixed the problem.